# Fastest way to use CSS

Tags: html, css

Good morning. There are three different ways to use CSS: first: via an extern file embed in the head like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">`, second: directly in the head like `<style> body {background-color:green;} h1 {color:blue;} p {color:yellow;}</style>` and third using a style attribute in HTML elements like `<h1 style="background-color:blue;">Blue background</h1>`.

My question is: which one is the fastest for the browser?

Comment: The 3rd way is fastest.

Comment: Is there a reason why this is important to you ? The performance boost that of using inline css is too trivial compared to the amount of performance boost (through other factors) using a CSS file.

Comment: @GoranJakovljevic There is no special reason I just want to know it, maybe there is a huge perfomance boost and I dont know him. If the third method does improve the performance maybe I should write the css directly in the code doesn't matter if it's confusing.

Comment: No, putting styling at element level would mean that you cannot cache the CSS style rules separately. Going first way would allow the caching to be done, which reducing the amount of load from the server on every request. Also if u have multiple elements that you would style the same, and there will be plenty of them, you are duplicating your code and creating bigger files for no reason.

Answer (score 2):

The speed difference between the three is negligible, though a `<link>` to an external sheet may be the slowest, depending on the amount of time to first byte (ttfb). If you have a multi page application where all pages use the same stylesheet, your page size goes down with an external stylesheet, since it will be downloaded once and then reused thanks to browser caches. That is also the most convenient way to change your CSS. Furthermore, any kind of CSS loading is trivial to the browser and you won't really notice the slowdown due the method you're using.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on a bunch of parameters of your css, and your page. I suggest you to read this article [Optimizing CSS delivery](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery#example) by Google, and [this one](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/optimize-css-delivery.html). In most cases the fastest and best option is to use external file specified in `<link>` tag. But remember that you need to concat all of your css files into one, cause each file is the roundtrip over network to your server and it will definitely decrease the page load speed.

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't know about the one big css file. I thought if I use external css it doesn't matter how many files I have

Comment: @DrSheldonTrooper, also try to look at css minification and concatenation. This operations will produce as small css file as it can be

Answer (score 1):

Using the external CSS files is the way to go. Not sure if the performance is going to better or at worse the same, but your code is going to be cleaner, learning to do things right from beginning, when code is smaller but getting right habits is quite important if you ask me.
If you want to read more about optimizing CSS, this is great read: [Optimize CSS delivery](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/optimize-css-delivery.html)

Answer (score 1):

Inline is probably the fastest way followed by the styles in the head of the document. Reason is that you save that 1 request (request, connect, wait, receive) of this css file.

But if you have more than one page the external file is probably faster because it is going to be cached by the browser on the first page and is loaded on the other pages out of that browser cache.

In cases of usage the external file is the best solution because its much cleaner. I prefer that even on single pages.

Answer (score 1):

It is up to your preference. I would prefer to use external stylesheet(s) which is also `<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">`. If you have multiple HTML oages, it would also make your coding cleaner and easier without having to copy and paste the code over.

I would keep the inline styling if i need to override any of my styling from the external styling, or i just want a quick styling to it. This would get pretty messy if you have all your styling coded inline.

Answer (score 1):

Dont do that :)

Speed between those 3 is really too trivial compared to the amount of performance boost (through other factors) using a CSS file.

One of these factors is caching. Using css file allow the caching to be done, which reducing the amount of load from the server on every request. Which IS MORE significant in matter of speed then placing it inline.

Then there is issue with duplicating code by painting a particular element via inline, where you can repaint multiple elements together via css.

And plenty more in links ppl sent above, so, even tho u are right that third is fastest, there are other factors which after included makes 1st way to be fastest.